# Custom Node painting in JavaFX

Tags: user-interface, javafx, paint, paintevent

In PySide you can override the `paintEvent()` method of a `QWidget` to control how the widget is painted on the screen. Is there an equivalent for `Node` in JavaFX?

---

In context: I'm in need of a way to display a custom image format on the screen. Constantly converting my format and JavaFX's `Image` so I can display it in an `ImageView` is too slow for me, in addition to being messier.

I've taken a look at `ImageView.java` and `Canvas.java`, but no luck. `ImageView` is using css, and `Canvas` appears to be doing something with the deprecated `impl_` methods, for which I've found no documentation on.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "`ImageView` is using css". You can either use a [`WritableImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) as the image provided to an `ImageView`, or use a [`Canvas`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) and its [`GraphicsContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html). The `GraphicsContext` has plenty of public API for drawing the image.

Comment: What is the image format?

Comment: @James_D @Kyllopardiun I didn't read too deep into it, but it appears `ImageView` displays its image by styling itself with the `-fx-image` CSS property, but the actual painting is done elsewhere. It might be in one of the `impl_` methods, but without docs I can't make sense of them. I have an array of `int`s representing the image data. It's an image editor I'm working on; the speed at which I can update the image view to reflect changes to the image data is an issue here, which is why I don't want to be converting between two formats all the time.

Comment: I don't understand sorbet, discussion of CSS and `impl_` methods seems irrelevant.  If you have an array ints which is a buffer representing the image data, why can't you use a WritableImage as James_D suggests (`writableImage.getPixelWriter().setPixels(...)`)?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the paint mechanisms in JavaFX changed towards a more event-based approach. To follow the JavaFX way, you should probably look at [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) or [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) and only update the display when the actual image data changes.

However, you could use the old Swing way in JavaFX, if you like:

```
public class MyPane extends Pane {
    private final Canvas canvas;

    public MyPane() {
        canvas = new Canvas(getWidth(), getHeight());
        getChildren().add(canvas);
        widthProperty().addListener(e -> canvas.setWidth(getWidth()));
        heightProperty().addListener(e -> canvas.setHeight(getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();

        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        gc.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.fillRect(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);

        // Paint your custom image here:
        gc.drawImage(someImage, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The above code would be the equivalence of this Swing code:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -969772195113348076L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.setColor(java.awt.Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20);

        // Paint your custom image here:
        g.drawImage(someImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will keep entire canvas in memory, not as in `paintComponent`